# React no rerender after url change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, react-router-dom

My route definition:

```
...{
path: '/profile/:id',
component: ProfilePage
}, ...
```

and then the mapping is:

```
{routes.map(({ path, component }) => {
        return (
            <Route
                exact
                key={path}
                path={path}
                component={component}
            />
        )
    })}
```

If I navigate from `*/main*` to `*/profile/3*` everything is fine. But if I am already on a profile and navigate to another profile with different ID `(*profile/3* -> *profile/5*)` the problem starts. The URL in the browser changes but the content does not rerender. Also the `useEffect` function is not called again. If I navigate to any other url and then start the search for a person, everything is fine again. So only a second call from profile to profile does not work.

My navigation in the list is done by

```
const onItemSelected = (event) => {
    const selectedPerson = event.itemData
    setShowSuggestions(false)
    setFilteredSuggestions([])
    setInput("")
    if(selectedPerson && selectedPerson.id)
      history.replace(`/profile/${selectedPerson.id}`);
}
```

My `useEffect` in `profile.js`

```
export default (props) => {
...
useEffect(() => {
    try {
        setLoading(true)
        const urlPath = window.location.href.split('/')
        const id = urlPath[urlPath.length - 1]
        loadProfile(id)

    } catch (e) {
        setLoading(false)
        history.push("/aufgabenliste")
    }

}, []);
```

I also tried `history.push()` but it didn't work too.

Comment: I found a workaround to create a listener with history.listen(...) and to check the url each time. But I guess this is not the state of the art..

Comment: Please include some more code. I don't know if `history` is the global window history or passed through some params in a React Router component.

Comment: Done.
history is from the useHistory()

Comment: I think you have to play with state. make a dispatched state and  set it on base of useparams hooks.

const [dispatched , setDispatched] = useState(false)

//set it to true on useEffect
{dispatched && return dom)

Comment: Why you're not using `useParams` to get the id, and than add it to effect dependecies array?

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution.
First of all it is much easier to load the ID from the props instead of accessing the window.location.href...

And the second step is to set the props as dependency in useEffect.
So the final code looks like:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    try {
        setLoading(true)
        const id = props.match.params.id
        loadProfile(id)
    } catch (e) {
        setLoading(false)
        history.push("/aufgabenliste")
    }

}, [props]);
```

Comment: Explain how this fixed the problem?